# Another! jqGrid question.. search not working

Tags: jquery-ui, search, jqgrid

Same one as my previous question, but this time another problem - the search box doesnt appear when the search icon is clicked... it worked yesterday, but not any more!
http://sysport.co.uk/admin/grid/TEST.php

Should work the same as:
trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Left hand side click new in 3.7 -> Multiple Search...

Really baffled me! It uses jquery-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you should change the list of the JavaScript files loaded from

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The file `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` must be loaded before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. The file `src/grid.loader.js` on the other side **contain the same files** which are already included in the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` plus `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` (see [developer version of jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ahow_to_install#development_installation)). Including two versions of jqGrid can follow to unpredictable results.

Comment: @rickyduck: You should additionally place the code from http://sysport.co.uk/admin/grid/37multiple.js inside `$(document).ready(function () {/*place your code here*/});`. I mean the file `37multiple.js` should be started not from `jQuery("#multiple37").jqGrid({`, but with `$(document).ready(function () {jQuery("#multiple37").jqGrid({...});...});`. You can also move the line `<script type="text/javascript" src="37multiple.js"></script>` from the `<body>` to the end of `<head>` after all other JavaScript files

Comment: @Oleg- got it working, now however the overlay sits on top of the search and containing div. The search isnt draggable when the class is removed via firebug. Using 1.8.9 with ui and including draggable: